# Ember.js event not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I wrote this very simple Ember code, but for some reason the event doesn't seem to fire when I press the button. Any tips?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      {{#view CounterView}}
        Counter: {{Counter.value}}

        <button {{action "increment"}}>Add 1</button>
      {{/view}}
    </script>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="handlebars-1.0.rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ember-1.0.pre.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      Counter = Ember.Object.create({
        value: 1,
      })

      CounterView = Ember.View.extend({
        increment: function(event) {
          Counter.incrementProperty('value');
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make the event system working, Ember.js needs an application to be created and initialized (the framework does it for you).

Applying your example to the default Ember.js starting jsfiddle, here is the result:

Html template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{#view MyApp.CounterView}}
    Counter: {{MyApp.counter.value}}
    <button {{action "increment"}}>Add 1</button>
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
//Thanks to @Trek Instructions:
//The following line creates one listener for each user event (e.g. 'click') and
//controls event delegation.
MyApp = Ember.Application.create();

MyApp.counter = Ember.Object.create({
  value: 1
});

MyApp.CounterView = Ember.View.extend({
  increment: function(event) {
    MyApp.counter.incrementProperty('value');
  }
});
```

​
Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6p6XJ/260/

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to read http://trek.github.com/, particularly the "The Smallest Viable Ember Application" part.

Starting from 1.0.pre, Ember apps require a router to be present. However, most of the documentation/examples on net refer to 0.9.5 era

trek guide + ember docs are a great way to start with the framework.